# nativescript angular modal statusBarStyle without actionbar

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to change the color of the text in the iOS statusbar that contains the carrier/time/battery indicators. I can do this providing I am using an actionbar and I can manually set in the Info.plist file.

The problem I am having is for the homepage I want white text in the statusbar but black text for modals. As both the homepage and modals do not have a visible actionbar I cannot change the statusBarStyle dynamically between them.

I have tried everything mentioned in the documentation but nothing seems to work with modals:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/change-status-bar-style-ios

Has anyone else ran into this issue and found a working solution? It seems like a fairly common scenario.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue did u find any solution for that?

Comment: Hi! Any update? I'm facing the same problem :/